# Нажатие нескольких кнопок в окне WPF

Tags: wpf

Есть несколько кнопок в окне приложения. Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на одну, а затем, не отпуская левую кнопку мыши переведя курсор на другие, другие кнопки тоже нажимались?

Comment: Придется реализовывать это функционал вручную, в качестве кнопок подойдет, например, `ToggleButton`

Comment: Обрабатываю событие MouseEnter, но как дополнительно обработать событие, что зажата левая кнопка мыши в момент входа курсора на кнопку?